# VS2008 Xaml Editor is totally unstable

Tags: visual-studio-2008, xaml

I have installed every patch I can find that deals with stability.  I have turned off intellisense in the XAML Editor.  I have setup XAML to only use the XML View (I never use preview).

VS2008 crashed multiple times an hour while editting XAML.  It is fine until the first time I open up a XAML file and then it is only a matter of time before it crashes or hangs.

Does ANYONE know if there is any available patch for this?  I simply cannot believe how BAD this is.  My teams productivity is down to less than 6 hours a day because of the number of times we have to restart visual studio, and/or wait to determine if a build has really HUNG, or is still working...

If there is not a patch, what the heck do we need to do?  I cannot wait for VS2010 to resolve this, assuming it will... which, at this point, I have my doubts.

HELP ME PLEASE!

Comment: yeah, the studio is pretty bad in this area.

Comment: I agree.. I have tried everything and it still sucks. Hopefully 2010 is better!

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried [using the source code editor](http://devlicious.com/blogs/christopher_bennage/archive/2009/02/04/an-essential-tip-for-working-with-xaml.aspx)?

> 1. Right-click on a XAML file in the Solution Explorer
> 2. Select "Open With..."
> 3. Select "Source Code (Text) Editor"
> 4. Click on "Set as Default"
> 5. Click OK
> 6. You're done!

Comment: Did this.  While it helped, I was still experiencing a huge amount of issues.

Comment: Certainly helped me. Didn't need the designer for a long time anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried narrowing this down to specific complaints, then entering Connect bugs on them at http://connect.microsoft.com/visualstudio/? It works a lot better than whining does, especially if you create bugs on narrow, specific, reproducible issues.

Since I suspect you'll generate many such bugs, please post them all here, as edits to your question, so we can all vote on them.

Comment: ...actually it was more of a rant than a whine.

Comment: i'm whining. vs2010 beta2 is terrible. freezes all the time for no reason even without the designed open

Comment: So, stop whining, and go _do_ something about it! Have you reported these problems?

Answer (score 0):

If you're unhappy with visual studios performance you can always try sharpdevelop. Sharpdevelop doesn't have a visual designer for xaml, but the editor is pretty stable.  Kaxaml is also a good alternative for xaml editing because it has wysiwym.

Comment: I have not tried SharpDevelop, I will investigate that further.  Kaxaml is a great tool, but I have not been able to get it to recognize the custom controls.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use the designer, you can map the .xaml extension to the XML Editor, which is far more stable. You can do this in the options pane. The only thing you lose is Intellisense, but I find it more than worth it.

Comment: Interesting idea. How do you do that?  This might be the best solution for us, at least for the time being.

Comment: Tools/Options/Text Editor/File Extension.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried editing your XAML with Expression Blend? It is much much easier than VS.

Comment: Being a developer, most on my team actually found it more difficult, Blend is more of a designer tool.  I also found it difficult to get our multi-project custom controls working correctly in it.